# Display values of multidimensional array returend from function

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
function sitemap_galerija($tablica)
{
    require("include/konekcija.php");

    if($tablica == 'kategorije')
    {
        // Connect do database

        ...

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result))
        {
            $kategorija['naziv'][] = $row["naziv"];
            $kategorija['naziv_url'][] = $row["naziv_url"];
        }

        return $kategorija;
    }   
}
```

I managed to print values of array but can't figure out how to handle with array keys.
I would like the print to be like this:

```
$kategorije = sitemap_galerija('kategorije');

foreach($kategorije as $kat)
{  
    echo  "<li><a href='$kategorija[naziv_url]'>$kategorija[naziv]</a></li>";
}
```

Ile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want your `$kategorija` array to use normal numbers as keys, and for each number you'd have an array wit the `naziv` and `naziv_url` keys:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result))
{
    // $kategorija['naziv'][] = $row["naziv"];
    // $kategorija['naziv_url'][] = $row["naziv_url"];
    $kategorija[] = array('naziv' => $row['naziv'], 'naziv_url' => $row['naziv_url']);
    // The following works as well, but then you store all the keys in the kategorija array and I don't know if that's what you want:
    // $kategorija[] = $row;
}
```

Then you can adjust your `foreach` loop to be something like:

```
foreach($kategorije as $kat)
{  
    echo  '<li><a href="' . $kat['naziv_url'] . '">' . $kat['naziv'] . '</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You really have to save relation between `naziv` and `naziv_url`, it'll help you in the future. Just get it from DB like this:

```
$kategorija[$row['naziv_url']] = $row["naziv"];
```

and then you can enumerate this array like this:

```
foreach($kategorija as $naziv_url => $naziv) {
}
```

Always use the value that you know is unique as keys, I supposed url in unique in this case.

Comment: This is great solution for this example of mine. But if I need to get more data from DB (id, date, etc.) than this is not good solution. But for just 2 variables this is really nice ;)
Thanks,
Ile

Comment: You always can use sub arrays :) Like in `$collection[$row['id']] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'value' => $row['value'])`. Or even better, as I always do lately, `$collection[$row['id']] = $row`.

Comment: Or multiple different sets of key->value if it makes more sense.

Comment: hmm, this $collection[$row['id']] = $row seems interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

You will need the key to iterate both arrays in parallel:

```
for ($i=0, $n=count($kategorije['naziv_url']); $i<$n; ++$i) {
    echo  "<li><a href='".$kategorija['naziv_url'][$i]."'>".$kategorija['naziv'][$i]."</a></li>";
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I think I'll satisfy with Joost's solution.